# Domain model and grouped data

Tags: grouping, hierarchical-data, domain-model

I'm starting to catch the domain model idea but there is one thing that I fail to see how this is realized in domain model - grouped data. The most obvious example is various reports, with or without dynamic column grouping and user specified order of columns.

I'll try to provide specific example. Imagine following domain model:

```
Orders [1-to-many] Positions [1-to-many] Production items
```

Displayed as simple 3 level list.

```
Order 1
- Position 1
  - Production item 1, length: 2.5, weight: 1.234
  - Production item 2, length: 2.5, weight: 2.345
  - Production item 3, length: 5, weight: 3.456
```

Then goes the requirement to modify Position level by adding "length" field (just for the display, the Position entity itself is NOT altered) from Production item and group by this field.

```
Order 1
- Position 1, length: 2.5
  - Production item 1, length: 2.5, weight: 1.234
  - Production item 2, length: 2.5, weight: 2.345
- Position 1, length: 5
  - Production item 3, length: 5, weight: 3.456
```

And next requirement is to add another SUMmed field "weight" from Production item level in Position level. Again, only on display.

```
Order 1
- Position 1, length: 2.5, weight: 3.579
  - Production item 1, length: 2.5, weight: 1.234
  - Production item 2, length: 2.5, weight: 2.345
- Position 1, length: 5, weight: 3.456
  - Production item 3, length: 5, weight: 3.456
```

What I need to change to achieve this "artifical" model?

Seems like some sort of composite value object is needed in place where goes Positions: all Position entity fields + size field + weight field. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NHibernate as your ORM tool, you can use the Projection functions to perform grouping and aggregate function such as 'sum' and 'count'. This leaves the problem of what entity to return from the query though, as your Position entity probably won't have the 'weight' field. I tend to just have a new entity (maybe entity is not the right word) called PositionQueryResult or something similar. Something to differentiate fromthe actual Position entity. This 'entity' has no behaviour - just properties that should be returned. I've not seen this advocated anywhere, but it works for me.

However, you refer to this as 'reporting'. One school of thought says that reporting should not be included in your domain, that it is something separate. This can be quite a good paradigm to follow, because ORM is better for Domain Model programming, but raw SQL is often better for reporting.